# Making Large Data Sets Faster in ArcGIS Online or Portal

Tags: arcgis-online, attribute-joins, performance, publishing, arcgis-portal

I have a sql view joined to a parcel layer for the entire city of New York (over 800k records). All data is registered to to the arcgis server. As you could imagine, this produces very slow response times in ArcGIS itself and when published to an online mapping service. Does anyone have any ideas on a different approach to linking this data or publishing methods to cut down loading times?

---

It looks like publishing a Tiled Service has improved speed but so far i am unable to toggle different layers off and on, furthermore, while my configured pop-ups remain in place, i am unable to reconfigure them.

Comment: Have you set scale-based visibility for the parcel layer? For example, configure ArcGIS Server to only make the layer visible when zoomed to a specific scale such as 1:10000. As you've seen, showing 800k parcels at once is going to be very intensive.

Comment: Definitely! First step i took was limiting the visibility to 1:24,000 and the response times are still pretty dismal

Comment: There's an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to provide additional information like this.

Comment: Does the SQL view (or tables it is based on) have an index on the column you are using for the join?